# How to delete temp files and personal user data?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I need to build a batch file that is run every 24 hours and deletes all of the current users temp files, browser cache, temp data, desktop files and download files.

I managed to get it working for the general Windows temp folders, but I am failing at adding the browser cache and user specific paths to desktop and downloads. Any help on how to do this would be appreciated.

```
del C:\Temp /S /Q /F
del C:\Temp /S /Q /A:H
FOR /D %%p IN ("C:\Temp\*") DO rmdir "%%p" /s /q
del C:\Windows\Temp /S /Q /F
del C:\Windows\Temp /S /Q /A:H
for /D %%p in ("C:\Windows\Temp\*") do rmdir "%%p" /s /q
```

Answer (score 0):

deleting temp files without checking if said files are in use at the moment, looks like might cause application errors. Unless you can guarantee no app is using any of those files for anything important I'd advise for another method.

Comment: is there any way for MS-DOS to end / close the file before deleting? I have never worked with DOS before...

Comment: It is not possible to delete temporary files being currently opened by any running process/application. But installers and uninstallers extract files to temporary files folders and sometimes some of these temporary files are kept in the temporary files folders until a restart of Windows is executed to remove or update files in the application folders during restart of Windows before the application or service is started again. So by deleting files in temporary files folder uncoordinated you can very easily break installations or uninstallations which means you can corrupt the entire machine.